# python crypto rsa issue

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, pycrypto

There seems to be a problem with RSA encryption/decryption in python Crypto package:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from os import urandom
def test(keylen, datalen, rand_len):
    k = RSA.generate(keylen)
    ok, fail = (0,0)
    for i in range(1000):
        a = urandom(datalen)
        if a == k.decrypt(k.encrypt(a, urandom(rand_len))):
            ok += 1
        else:
            fail += 1
    return ok, fail
```

No matter what combinations of keylen/datalen/rand_len i do i can't get it to decrypt 100% of times. Is it only my installation of Crypto?

```
>>> test(1024,128,0)
(853, 147)
>>> test(1024,127,0)
(996, 4)
>>> test(2048,127,0)
(994, 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from os import urandom
def test(keylen, datalen, rand_len):
    k = RSA.generate(keylen)
    ok, fail = (0,0)
    for i in range(1000):
        a = urandom(datalen).lstrip(b'\x00')
        if a == k.decrypt(k.encrypt(a, urandom(rand_len))):
            ok += 1
        else:
            fail += 1
    return ok, fail
```

explanation:

pycrypto operates on numbers, not on bytes internally, that means leading zeroes will not be considered. `encrypt` and `decrypt` are very low-level.

for signing you should use the [`Signature`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Signature-module.html) package (pycrypto2.5+), which takes care of correctly padding you message. otherwise you have to pad your message yourself.

Comment: Thanks!

Now I know how to fix it!

Comment: Also noticed when decrypting crypto also treats strings as numbers, and omits first '\x00'. This should be prepended back to decrypted string.

Answer (score 1):

Each decryption failure occurs for input strings beginning with NUL (`\x00'`). If you compare the original string with the decrypted version you will notice that the original begins with `'\x00'` and that the recovered version will have the first byte removed, e.g.

```
>>> a = '\x00\xa4\x8aE\xb5,\x1a\x95)Q'
>>> b = k.decrypt(k.encrypt(a, urandom(rand_len)))
>>> a == b
False
>>> len(a)
10
>>> len(b)
9
>>> a
'\x00\xa4\x8aE\xb5,\x1a\x95)Q'
>>> b
'\xa4\x8aE\xb5,\x1a\x95)Q'
```

You'll notice that, other than the first byte, a and b are the same.

Obviously NUL is important for C string termination, but I am surprised that it fails in this way rather than simply treating the original string as an empty string. I guess that the library just skips over any leading NUL and encrypts with the remainder of the string.